# How to save items from a FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, local-storage, react-native-flatlist

I'm working on a simple language learning app and am rendering a flatlist of flashcards using `CardsList` and `CardItem`, here are the components:

```
const CardsList = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={cards}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CardItem card={item} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const CardItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image />
      <SaveButton /
    <View>
  )
};
```

The `cards` data is currently being passed in from a separate json file.

I'd like to implement functionality to the `SaveButton` component which allows the user to copy certain cards that will be displayed on another page, so that they have a separate list of cards they are struggling with that they want to give more practice to.

Can anyone recommend the best way I could go about this? Would it be best to push the items into a new array first? I would also like the items to be stored to memory on the other page? Is local storage an appropriate way to tackle this, or would I need to involve a database. The list of flash cards is likely to be in excess of around 2,500.

Comment: If your application will not goes for live and might not contain large data sets, then device storage is best and easy way to store data.
You can sync (upload) it on server after give app update to user.

Comment: In short, if data is not important to update on server then I would suggest to store it on device as it is faster then server's API call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously an API + DB is the best way to handle user data. But if you don't want or can't make it, you can store those data in the device.

Use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to store in your device. Be aware of that method can only store strings, so you need to stringify and parse your JSON.

Store data

```
const favList = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: "My fav 1"
    }
]

AsyncStorage.setItem('user_fav_list', JSON.stringify(favList))
```

Get data

```
const favList = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_fav_list')
const userFavList = JSON.parse(favList)
```